# how to cut out a piece of a string with javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am having a string like below and i want to cut out the T with the time from it like below:

```
var string = '2021-05-10T08:00,2021-05-11T08:00,2021-05-12T08:00';
```

My new string should look like this:

```
var new_string = '2021-05-10,2021-05-11,2021-05-12';
```

How can i do that?

I tried with `.replace` function but the problem is that the time is not always `08:00`

Comment: jQuery is a framework mostly adapted to work with the DOM. You *could* do string manipulation with it but it makes very little sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it into an array and process each chunk. `map` is a good function for this

```js
 var string = '2021-05-10T08:00,2021-05-11T08:00,2021-05-12T08:00';
    var newstring = string.split(",").map(el => el.split('T')[0]).join(",");
    console.log(newstring);
```