# how to remove part of values from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with date & time like below:

```
$array = array('2021-05-04T10:00', '2021-05-05T10:00', '2021-05-06T10:00');
```

From each value, the `T10:00` should be cut off, so that my new array looks like this:

```
$new_array = array('2021-05-04', '2021-05-05', '2021-05-06');
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: With date conversion, string replacement... have you attempted any of that?

Comment: [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506045/how-to-cut-out-a-piece-of-a-string-with-javascript-jquery/67506118?noredirect=1#comment119318658_67506118

Comment: @MagnusEriksson my mistake, but it is otherwise exactly the same question, posted by the same author.

Comment: I agree, i asked this same question for JS but i got an issue with that so i decided to do it with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array('2021-05-04T10:00', '2021-05-05T10:00', '2021-05-06T10:00');
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $a) {
  $a = explode('T', $a)[0];
  array_push($new_array, $a);
}
```

Comment: Is this ok? hope so.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what i was looking for. Thnx

Comment: Thanks a lot. See you.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the array by `array_map` with callback function take only first 10 chars, Which represent time.

```php
$array = array('2021-05-04T10:00', '2021-05-05T10:00', '2021-05-06T10:00');
$new_array = array_map(fn($time)=>substr($time, 0, 10), $array);
```

```php
print_r($new_array);
```

**Prints:**

```
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 2021-05-04
    [1] => 2021-05-05
    [2] => 2021-05-06
)
*/
```

Comment: Great solution in 2 lines of code! Super!

Answer (score 2):

> the T10:00 should be cut off

If you have a constant time `T10:00` and want to get rid of it just replace it with empty!

```php
$array = array('2021-05-04T10:00', '2021-05-05T10:00', '2021-05-06T10:00');
$new_array = array_map(fn($time)=>str_replace('T10:00', '', $time), $array);

print_r($new_array);
//Array ( [0] => 2021-05-04 [1] => 2021-05-05 [2] => 2021-05-06 )
```